# UPDATED : How to determine "payer address" in "address.transfer(amount)"?

Tags: accounts, address.transfer, wallet-transfer, payable, payments

Consider we a function as follows :

```
address public recipient; 

function settlement(uint256 amount) public {

        recipient = msg.sender;
        recipient.transfer(amount);

    }
```

Then the `recipient` by invoking this function as follows (using `web3.js`), tries to receive the `amount` :

```
contractInstance.methods.settlement(10).send({ from: '0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c' }, function(error, result) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(result)
});
```

So, the address `0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c` must receive `10 wei`, but from which `address` ? Who is the `payer` ? and this `10 wei` has been ***reduced*** from `which account address` ?

Meanwhile, since we did not use **`payable`** for the `settlement` function, this `ether` ***transfer will be done correctly*** ?

**UPDATE :** In case we mark `payable` in the `constructor` of the `contract`, then does we need to mark the `settlement` function ? And the `recipient` will be sent the `amount` from the `balance` of the `contract` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
recipient.transfer(amount);
```

transfers `amount` wei from the contract's balance to the `recipient`. This line:

```
recipient = msg.sender;
```

means that the recipient is the account that called the function.

So when you call the function from the address `0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c`, with the parameter `10`, that address will receive 10 wei, paid from the contract. (This is assuming that the contract call succeeds, which it should as long as the contract has at least 10 wei.)

> Meanwhile, since we did not use payable for the settlement function, this ether transfer will be done correctly ?

Yes, a function only needs to be marked `payable` if it's going to *receive* ether. You don't need to mark functions that *send* ether.

This blog post might help understand the basics of receiving and sending ether: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/15/writing-a-contract-that-handles-ether/.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no transfer of value, since your code calling the function does not send any. If you would mark the function payable, the value would first be added to the smart contract's balance, and transfered to the recipient from there.

Comment: Thanks, so do you mean that if I mark `function settlement(uint256 amount) public payable {recipient = msg.sender; recipient.transfer(amount);}` then the `ether` will be transferred to the `0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c` ? but we did not determine who is the `payer` yet ? How can we do it ? Thank you

Comment: as you set the recipient to be the `msg.sender`, the ether will actually "return" to you. The sender of the ether is your account, if you send some ether along with the transaction. You can also build a contract of course, that can store value and allow you (or whoever) to transfer the ether it holds.

Comment: Thanks, so if I well understood, in case the `contract` `1.` has a `balance` and `2.` is `payable`, then I can call the `settlement` function with the form of `contractInstance.methods.settlement(10).send({ from: '0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c' }, function(error, result) {console.log(error);console.log(result)});` and **without** need for marking `payable` for `settlement` since the contract is `payable`. I'm right ? Thank you

Comment: "There will be no transfer of value, since your function does not send any." Could you explain what you mean? The function is only two lines long, and the second line transfers ether.

Comment: My bad smarx, I meant to say "the code he uses to call the function". Sas: Depending on your usecase your contract function can accept ether >and< transfer it somehwere (all in one transaction), or just transfer some ether it already holds >without< accepting any ether in that particular function call/transaction. You're the boss of your piggybank, you can 1. throw something in, 2. throw something in and let some pennies drop out, too, or 3. just let some pennies drop out.